# VB.net Inconsistant Thread Sleep Timer

Tags: .net, vb.net, sleep, thread-sleep

Ok so I have been playing with VB.net and brainstorming ways to accomplish launching a thread reliably every 60 seconds reguardless of how long the prior thread took to do it's work.  Here is my question.  Given the following code:

```
    Dim intTemp As Integer
    intTemp = 2
    Do While intTemp > 1
        Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Report\Report\Stream.txt", True)
        intTemp = intTemp + 1
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)

        objWriter.Write(intTemp & " " & Date.Now & " " & Date.Now.Millisecond & vbCrLf)
        objWriter.Close()
    Loop
```

Produces this in the stream.txt file.

```
3 4/5/2011 9:41:27 AM 807
4 4/5/2011 9:41:32 AM 812
5 4/5/2011 9:41:37 AM 817
6 4/5/2011 9:41:42 AM 822
7 4/5/2011 9:41:47 AM 826
8 4/5/2011 9:41:52 AM 831
9 4/5/2011 9:41:57 AM 836
10 4/5/2011 9:42:02 AM 841
11 4/5/2011 9:42:07 AM 799
```

My assumption for this output would be that the time between each line would have to be exactly 5000 milliseconds plus the time it takes to execute the rest of the loop which could vary given that there could be an unknown delay due to disk IO.  My problem is that looking at lines 10 and 11 and subtracting gives me a difference of 4,958 milliseconds.  So my question is what the heck is going on there?  How is it possible to get a difference of less than 5000 milliseconds when I have told the thread to sleep for 5000 milliseconds before completing the process.  What am I missing?

Comment: I guess the OS scheduled the thread to run again a little before 5 seconds elapsed. Doesn't sound so bad.

Comment: Right, my only concern with the timing is that I will be collecting data from an external source that is also timed.  If in the end my timer drifts I risk losing datapoints.  You are right that it appears to accomplish what it is being asked to do in the larger sense even if the individual time differences aren't perfect.

Comment: `Thread.Sleep` is generally not appropriate for the timing task in general. Consider [`Threading.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx). This still doesn't make all guarantees and a more advanced approach (ext. lib) or spin-waits may be required. Also make sure execution time is calculated from `x = start + i * m` and not `x += m` as the latter will introduce errors in many cases as in the above example. With a discreet formula it is always able to adjust back.

Comment: You should add the fact that this test was run on a VM to your question. I let your test run for 10 minutes and was unable to reproduce the results on Windows7.

Comment: @Seth Reno - Thanks for the tip and I will always remember that in the future.  Furthermore thank you so much for taking the time to run this test for 10 minuets!  Of course you didn't have to do only that while it was running but it would have taken you some time to look through the resulting file.  Again thanks!  This was my first question here and everyone has been extremely helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementation Suggestion: If you need timing precision, instead of a Do/Loop inside of a thread (with `Thread.Sleep`), just use an instance of the [`System.Timers.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx) class (this is very different from the old WinForms "Timer" object back in pre-.NET days). This will let you specify a `TimeSpan` between method calls.

Although, I can't vouch for true "precision" between `Thread.Sleep` vs. a `Timer` instance (I just assumed a `Timer` would be more accurate, given that Timekeeping is its primary function)... but perhaps someone could write up a quick test?

Comment: Thanks!  I am glad that you said that because I have already started down that road also believing that it would be more accurate to launch an async thread from the timer.tick handler.  I am glad that someone else came up with the same conclusion!

Answer (score 3):

First, understand that all major operating systems, especially those with multitasking capabilities will never be capable of landing timers down to the millisecond. The architecture simply doesn't support it.

Second, with the idea in mind that there will be some delay, if a setting of 5000 milliseconds were set by the underlying frameworks, operating system and whatever else is involved your code would *never* fire at 5000 milliseconds and always some x number of milliseconds after. What you're observing is most likely the operating system keeping some record as to the average delay and adjusting the timeout value accordingly in an attempt to land closer to 5000 milliseconds on average.

You can read about [real time operating systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_operating_system) to get more information.

Comment: It would be interesting to ask then: Does `Thread.Sleep` in Windows (say, 7/2008) make a guarantee about the *minimum* sleep duration if not interrupted? The maximum is not guaranteed of course. I would have guessed it was the time passed to `Thread.Sleep` (e.g. overrage-rounding only).

Comment: While theoretically I'm sure some minimum guarantee exists I'd be surprised if it were heavily documented. Simply for the fact that anyone relying on the OS to maintain any guarantees at the millisecond level is either approaching the problem incorrectly or trying to use the OS in a manner that was not intended.

Regardless, this doesn't prevent anyone from coding in some kind of minimum since obviously the expired milliseconds can be determined and there's nothing stopping the developer from throwing it back into sleep mode if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You also have to consider the time that it takes to instantiate, open & close a new StreamWriter. If you do this outside of the loop the results will be much closer to what you expect.

For example:

```
  Dim builder As New Text.StringBuilder()
  For i As Integer = 0 To 10
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
    builder.AppendLine(String.Format("{0} {1} {2}", i, Now, Now.Millisecond))
  Next
  IO.File.WriteAllText("c:\sleepTest.txt", builder.ToString)
```

Produces this output:

```
0 4/5/2011 3:15:35 PM 974
1 4/5/2011 3:15:36 PM 988
2 4/5/2011 3:15:37 PM 988
3 4/5/2011 3:15:38 PM 988
4 4/5/2011 3:15:39 PM 989
5 4/5/2011 3:15:40 PM 989
6 4/5/2011 3:15:41 PM 989
7 4/5/2011 3:15:42 PM 989
8 4/5/2011 3:15:43 PM 989
9 4/5/2011 3:15:44 PM 989
10 4/5/2011 3:15:45 PM 989
```

Comment: But wouldn't that result in a longer time, now a shorter time?

Comment: This is assuming that you can keep a file lock on the file without any other repercussions from other programs trying to access it.

Comment: Agreeing with SpikeX here. What would be better would be to simply save all these lines into a string builder which takes very little processing time. Once the loop is done then open up the file and write out the entire contents of the string builder.

Comment: Thanks I hadn't really thought of that.  I was assuming that the time was due to the disk IO subsystem competing for resources since that's the slowest part of a modern system.  Your test case is very interesting and I may have to reassess my previous assumptions!!

Comment: @Jarred, @Spencer Ruport - changed code per your suggestions.

Comment: @pst - yeah, I completely misunderstood the question :P

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your system clock was updated in the middle of the loop.

Comment: Perhaps!  I hadn't tought of that.  You could be right there because I am developing on a VM which has to have it's clock synced by the hypervisor.  I may have to run this test on another host machine with the os running on the metal instead of being virtualized to see if the results are different!

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your connundrum is pretty simple really.  There is no guarantee that two statements will execute in the same time slice.  Because you have multiple calls in a single statement, it's even worse.

It's quite possible that your call to DateTime.Now and DateTime.Now.Millisecond could occur nearly a second apart (particularly if some garbage collection were going on in between).

I'm not saying that IS your problem, but as written that possibility exists.  You can avoid that possibility by capturing the time in a variable.

```
Dim dt as DateTime
dt = DateTime.Now
objWriter.Write(intTemp & " " & dt & " " & dt.Millisecond & vbCrLf)
```

Comment: Ah!  I believe you are correct there!  I hadn't thought of it that way I was assuming (incorrectly apparently) that being on the same line would translate that it would occur within the same time slice when it was translated into machine code.  But I completely agree with your point.