# How to play sound by matching system time and gridview contains time?

Tags: vb.net

I have a application which contains two label and one grid view. In Labels Current Time showing EST & IST . and In a Grid View it showing Job name & time. I have setup all the data in to grid view and current time on label. now i want to play alarm when current time match with grid time. Please suggest me how i can do it. Note : there is lots of job which uses same time so for those jobs alarm must be played once only.

Comment: Thread is very helpful to you search with google using thread

Comment: Can you provide me a simple code which compare system time and and time stored in a grid-view using thread?

Comment: please help to resolve this query as soon as early... Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5557817/vb-net-inconsistant-thread-sleep-timer

Comment: http://www.dotnetperls.com/sleep-vbnet

Comment: Search with google this Heading 'time sleep using  thread in vb.net'

Comment: Thank You Very Much SenthilKumar. I am trying the above solutions :-) :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add timer to detect any match between current time and DataGridView values.

with interval = 1 .. 1000 (less  than a second)

then add the following code into the timer:

```
    Dim grid_date As DateTime
    Dim Alarm As Boolean = False
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In **DataGridView1**.Rows
        grid_date = row.Cells(*1*).Value
        If grid_date.ToLongTimeString= DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeStringThen
            Alarm = True
            'do something you want with this row
            **DataGridView1**.Rows.Remove(row)
        End If
    Next
    If Alarm Then My.Computer.Audio.PlaySystemSound(Media.SystemSounds.Beep)
```

note that "*1*" is the number of "*Time*" column in the **DataGridView1**.
you can play a .wav sound file by replacing **PlaySystemSound** with **Play**(*"c:\alarm.wav"*)

Comment: Maher @ Thanks for the help . but one more issue with timer control is that tick event not run with system second.
I have set timer control's tick property for 1sec. it was ticked every 1sec. but when it fire than the the system time might b changed or code re executes due to 1 sec. so dis the issue coming with timer control.

so can you please suggest me what next i have to do?

Comment: yup it won't run with system clock.
if you're worry about that clock might be changed during timer tick, then I suggest you to store the "now" time in a variable before the statement "For Each.." so the "now" become fixed temporarily.
here's what I mean:
dim now_time as DateTIme = DateTime.now
for each.....
..
If grid_date.ToLongTimeString = now_time.ToLongTimeString Then..
finally, u can change the interval to any value less than a second like 500 ,for example.